# Leaflet Map not showing in bootstrap div

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

This is a super odd problem that I can not figure out. I have my div with the map and its css styling. The Leaflet map is showing up in one rectangle and not in the div. Its as if the z index is wrong, but I can not figure it out.
The JS is in the document.ready function. I added a border around the map div just to show how off everything is.
[image]

CSS:

```
#map {width:100%;height:100%;margin-left:10px;margin-top:40px}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="showTravel" class="row" style="display:none">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        <h2 style="margin-top:-18px">All Travelers</h2>
        <div id="travelContent">
            <div id=map></div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var map=L.map('map',{
        minZoom:2,
    maxZoom:18
}).setView([x,y],16);

var buildingIcon=L.icon({
    iconUrl:'/images/bicon.png',
    iconSize:[25,40],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -20],
    iconAnchor: [14, 38]
});

L.marker(x,y],{
    icon:buildingIcon,
    title:'town, state'
})
.bindPopup('<b>first last</b><br>Email: email address<br>Cell: phone number')
.addTo(map);

mapLink='<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + mapLink,
    maxZoom:18
}).addTo(map);
```

I have fixed the **overlapping problem**, but the last problem still exists i.e.,

When the page loads and the map is rendered on the `document.ready()` the map is only visible in the **top left corner** of the screen. And If I changes the size of the browser (maximize,minimize) then the map refreshes correctly.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: It is 3.3 just to confirm

Comment: could you possibly need a `position: relative;` on your `#map`?

Comment: I would also add proper quotation marks around your ID in the html. See `<div id=map>`

Comment: No that did not make a difference, I am thinking it may be conflicting CSS with bootstrap but I can not find any place that would be an issue

Comment: In previous bootstrap versions their `img { max-width: 100%; }` rule used to conflict with map tiles. But my understanding was that it was fixed in 3+. I would try `#map img { max-width: none }`, just to be sure though.

Comment: Please check if you have included leaflet `css` file

Comment: I figured out why it was overlapping the div, but one problem that still exists is that the map only shows one rectangle still and the rest isn't loading. But if I move the browser to change its size the whole map now loads.

Comment: Please format your code better.

Comment: Is the bootstrap div is inside a tab? means the div is hidden by default and you open up by clicking on the tab or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the following function once the map is opened:

```
map.invalidateSize();
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: This wouldn't work using it when the map opened, but i set a timeout for one second after the map opens and then call this and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used it with hided divs, which appear after a click. The tiles were also not visible, so I added map.invalidateSize() to the jQuery function where the div is set visible. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
$('#showTravel').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  //creation of map
})
```

Or search in event of showing the div and into function creating the map

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue to display map inside Bootstrap Tabs. I have fixed it by using -

```
 $('#gmap').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    //clear map first
    clearMap();
    //resize the map
   map.invalidateSize(true);
   //load the map once all layers cleared
   loadMap();
})
```