# leaflet map is moved out of div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, leaflet

I'm trying to show a leaflet map inside a div tag. Unfortunately it gets moved out of the tag.

[image: leaflet outside of div tag]

This is my angular directive:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import esri from 'esri-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

class MapDirective {

    constructor() {
        this.resctrict = 'E';
        this.controller = MapController;
    }

    link(scope, element) {

        let map = L.map(element[0]).setView([51.505, -0.09], 8);

        esri.tiledMapLayer({
            url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer"
        }).addTo(map);


    }

    /**
     * @returns {MapDirective}
     */
    static directiveFactory() {
        return new MapDirective();
    }
}
```

And this is my html template code:

```
<h1>Leaflet Map Integration</h1>

<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    <map></map>
</div>
```

I already tried adding a

```
map.invalidateSize();
```

mentioned here [Leaflet Map not showing in bootstrap div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030949/leaflet-map-not-showing-in-bootstrap-div) but that did not help.

The full project code can be found at [github](https://github.com/pluess/woodstore/tree/5812b37c8eee62b1e0b6ca003075f6eb7a723b4b).

Comment: you need to add `map` id to your div.

Comment: @Ale No need for that, quoting the [Leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-l.map): `L.Map( <HTMLElement|String> id, <Map options> options)` - "Instantiates a map object given a div element (or its id)". This seems to pass an HTML element, which is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the getting started there is this statement:

> Make sure the map container has a defined height, for example by
>   setting it in CSS.

To bad something that important is only mentioned there.

I changed the directive type from "E" to "EA". This makes it possible to change the template into

```
<h1>Leaflet Map Integration</h1>

<div>
    <div map style="height: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

And everything is working as expected.