# Leaflet map not showing in tab. I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 if this could be a problem?

Tags: tabs, leaflet

I implemented leaflet map and it shows correctly outside tab or if it is an active tab but if I put it inside tab that is not active then I can see only the little corner of the map and zoom in and out controls.
Interestingly if I zoom in or out the browser with CTRL and + or - the map is shown correctly.
How can I sort this out?
Any idea?

Thanks.

Screenshot
https://ibb.co/iPS8TL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data-toggle tab does not download Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet Map not showing in bootstrap div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030949/leaflet-map-not-showing-in-bootstrap-div)

Comment: No guys. The corner of the map is still downloaded.

Comment: Yes guys. Both of the suggested dupes describe exactly that. "Typically, it downloads tiles only for the fraction of the container it thinks is shown. This can be a single tile in the top left corner in the case of a container that was entirely hidden at map initialization time."

Comment: Could I send you Peeebeee the source code to PM to take a look?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in the suggested dupes?

Comment: Yes, I tried all things that you posted. It doesn't work for me but you pointed right. This is the same problem that I face but I couldn't sort this out with map.invalidateSize(true);